# Is there a way to record down the sequence of Excel formula calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When press `F9` or call `Calculate` in VBA, formulas in Excel get executed. However, the sequence is done by Excel itself, up to the dependency constraints in formula dependency. Is there a way to record down the calculation process?

for example,

- I put `10` in cell `A1` and `20` in `A2`;
- put `=A1+A2` in `A3`, it
  shows `30`;
- put `=A1*A2` in `A4`, it shows `200`;
- put `=A3-A4` in
  `A5`, it shows `-170`.

I hope there's a way to show that calculation sequence is 
 - `0` for cells `A1` and `A2`
 - `1` for cells `A3` and `A4`
 - `2` for cell `A5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the last calculation sequence used you could extract the calculation chain part from the XLSX/XLSM file and decode it.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278336.aspx as a starting point

For small scale tests you can use a Calculation Sequence tracking UDF like this one
http://www.decisionmodels.com/Downloads/CalcTrace.zip

But note that the calculation sequence dynamically changes at each calculation.
To use CalcTrace unzip the XLA and unblock it (right-click the XLA->Properties->Unblock). Then open the XLA as if it was a workbook. For each formula you want to see the calculation sequence for (for example A4 and A5 add a formula alongside =CalcSeqCountRef(A4) and =CalcSeqCountRef(A5). This returns a count that is incremented by 1 each time CalcSeqCountRef is calculated. Since CalcSeqCountRef(A4) is dependent on A4 it is calculated each time A4 is calculated.

Comment: google for xml calculation chain. The CalcSeqCountRef() UDF increments a counter each time the cell that is referenced by its parameter is calculated: eg CalcSeqCountRef(A1) increments and returns a counter whenever A1 is calculated.

Comment: it's working! now I figured it out how to use it! Thanks a lot, would  you pls explain a bit on how it's done?